# Codeigniter anchor can't find link

Tags: codeigniter, anchor

I am using CodeIgniter to design a website, and I am having trouble getting anchor to work correctly.

Here is how I am using it. It is used in a file in views folder of application in codeigniter.

```
 <?php echo anchor('/profile', 'PROFILE'); ?>
```

My intention is to have anchor load the profile controller, which is in the controllers of application in codeigniter. However, when I clink on the link, it says that the the file is not found.

I autoload the url helper functions alreader, and other functions from that file are working, like     `site_url()` .

I don't know what I could have missed? Do you ave any suggestions? This is my second project with codeigniter, so I am still learning.

EDIT: Yes, I am following the naming convention in codeigniter, and the file has an index function. I tried without the forward slash and it still gives the same result.

The HTML link that this produces is `localhost/profile`. This is what I Should get right? Since for codeigniter, it's `url/controller/function`. I did a mod rewrite to remove index.php from the url, but that shouldn't be a problem, should it? I'll try and check the base url again.

Comment: Check the class name of the controller. And make sure you follow the naming convention.

Comment: do you have the index function in your controller?

Comment: can you please provide a specific example - i.e.  "?php echo anchor('/profile', 'PROFILE'); ?>" - and then the ACTUAL link from the HTML page that it produces? It will then be easy to work out

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need the leading forward slash?
Have you tried:

```
<?php echo anchor('profile', 'PROFILE'); ?>
```

You would only be using the slash if you are trying to get into the "profile" sub folder inside your controllers folder.
What helps me when urls get confusing is to type into the browser the full url to the path I want to get to (to make sure I'm not getting a 404, etc).  From there you can start from the end and go back to see what you are missing.

But you generally want to start with a controller name and add the function you are calling like:

```
anchor(controllerName/functionName)
```

See [CodeIgniter URL Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) for examples.

EDIT: also - you may need to check what your config base_url is set to.  if there's fancy .htaccess stuff happening, your base_url needs to be set properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution go to config/constants and define SITE_URL there and set its value to

```
http://localhost/myprojectname/index.php.
```

Then use it here like this.

```
<?php echo anchor(SITE_URL.'/profile', 'PROFILE'); ?>
```